# How to use window.matchmedia in React with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to build a simple dark mode toggle switch in React Typescript. I have built this already in React with plain js using `useState` and `window.matchmedia('(prefers-color-scheme dark)').matches`. This classic approach does not seem to work in Typescript. I get the following error: `RefereceError: window is not defined`.

I tried using the useState function as follows: `const [state, setState] = useState(window.matchmedia("prefers-color-scheme: dark").matches);`
This returns the Error mentioned above.
How can I solve this in React with Typescript?

Comment: `ReferenceError` is not a typescript error, it is a runtime error saying that `window` object doesn't exist. Do you have SSR? Is this code run in some other environment than browser?

Comment: Hello Alex, the code runs in a regular next.js environment as described in the react docs. I run the code in my Chrome browser. You are right I is an error at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. This was a very trivial mistake, sorry. We have to use the React hook: **useEffect** for **window**
Now my code looks like this:

```
const [prefCol, setPrefCol] = useState("dark");
useEffect(() => {
   let mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;
   if(mediaQuery) {setPrefCol("dark");}
   else {setPrefCol("light");}
});
```

A very simple check to see what system preference is currently used. Hopefully that helps someone :)